# Free current and free charges

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electricity

In case of electromagnetic waves in a magnetized material, does no free charge always imply that free current is zero?

Answer (score 2):

There can be situations where we have identical amounts of positive and negative free charge even though the total amount of charge is zero.

Although the net amount of free charge is zero in such a case, positive and negative free charged particles can move independently of each other.

A good example of this is current moving in a circuit. In this case the net charge density is zero everywhere. But their still exists free current.